# data is not inserted into Ms-Access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I’m not able to insert data of JTextField into Ms-Access using JDBC Connectivity

```
private void addOperation()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        System.out.println("\n Drivers are Properly Loaded");
        //String url = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=" + "E:\\Employee\\Employee.mdb";
        String url="jdbc:odbc:ABC";
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Connection Established");
        sql="insert into Emp(Reg_no, F_Name, M_Name, L_Name)values('"+r_no.getText()+"',"+t1.getText()+",'"+t2.getText()+"',"+t3.getText()+")";
        st=con.createStatement();
        st.executeUpdate(sql);

    }
}
```

Comment: please edit your text: what results do you get? what results do you expect? Please format your code as code.

Comment: Edit your question to contain the exact error that occurs when you run your code. Without the exact, and complete, output including error messages people can only make wild guesses as to what is wrong.